# Identify "UNIX-specific directories" in macOS

Tags: macos, unix, filesystem, folders, metadata

According to [Apple's File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW7), macOS includes so-called UNIX-specific directories:

> The directories in this category are inherited from traditional UNIX installations. They are an important part of the system’s BSD layer but are more useful to software developers than end users.

These are hidden to the user, and include `/bin`, `/tmp`, `/dev`, `/usr`, and more.

My question is: how can I identify these directories?

I notice that `chflags` has a `UF_HIDDEN` flag, which I thought might help, however while `UF_HIDDEN` is set on `/bin` and `/dev`, it is not set on `/tmp` (so it must not be set for all UNIX-specific directories).  I was also wondering if `mdls` could help, as I notice the following:

```
kMDItemSupportFileType = (
    MDSystemFile
)
```

However, this value (`MDSystemFile`) is present on `/bin/bash` as well as many other files that are not UNIX-specific directories (as they are files).  I thought it might be possible that the file is a UNIX-specific directory if the `kMDItemSupportFileType` contains `MDSystemFile`, *and* the file is a directory, however this theory also fell apart as `MDSystemFile` is not present for `/tmp`.

How can these UNIX-specific directories be identified?

Comment: What does „unix-specific“ mean, what is an example for a non-unix-specific directory? And what do you intend to do with the information once you can distinguish them?

Comment: Also, the linked page seems to list them already, what more do you need to know?

Comment: @nohillside The page states "Some of the more important directories that are hidden include," which implies that the listing is incomplete.  Also on the page, "UNIX-specific" directories is defined by Apple: "UNIX-specific directories. The directories in this category are inherited from traditional UNIX installations. They are an important part of the system’s BSD layer."  Once I have distinguished them, I will know that the directory is hidden from the user because it is a system directory.

Comment: Which practical problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @nohillside programmatically determine whether a file or directory is hidden in macOS.

Comment: @nohillside do you know why this question is being downvoted?

Comment: If you compare the listing in Apple's documentation with the directory structure found in FreeBSD (for example: https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/6.1-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/handbook/dirstructure.html) you will see that it is mostly complete (one can argue whether `/cores` belongs to the listing). Note that `/mnt`, `/proc`, `/rescue`, `/root` and `/stand` from the link above don't exist in macOS. As for why the question is being downvoted, I'd venture to say it is because it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @jaume, thanks you for your edits, and thanks for showing me the BSD resource.  Regarding clarify of my question: I clearly stated my question twice, yet it is still unclear what I am trying to accomplish?  Any tips on how to be more clear in future would be appreciated.

Comment: @JakeIreland It might be clear to you, but it's not really clear to me (I haven't downvoted you though). I get that you want to identify hidden files or folders programmatically - but you haven't explained why and to what purpose. I.e. when you know how to do it, what are you going to use it for? - If people knew that, they might be able to suggest much better or simpler ways of going about this. In addition, it is very unclear from your question whether you are talking about files and folders hidden by Finder, or hidden by "macOS in general" (if that makes any sense at all).

Answer (score 2):

To programmatically determine whether a file or directory is hidden in macOS, use the [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager). This can be done via AppleScript, Objective-C, or Swift.

## NSURLIsHiddenKey

Check if a file or directory has the [`NSURLIsHiddenKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlishiddenkey) attribute associated and that it is set to true:

> Key for determining whether the resource is normally not displayed to users, returned as a Boolean NSNumber object (read-write).

Note that file and directory names beginning with a period (`.`) are hidden, regardless of this attribute.

Use a function such as NSFileManager's [enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1409571-enumeratoraturl) to enumerate the file system and query the desired attributes.

> Returns a directory enumerator object that can be used to perform a deep enumeration of the directory at the specified URL.

Answer (score 1):

There's no technical distinction as such in play here. The term "UNIX-specific directory" is not a "thing" in terms of the macOS operating system.

The name only comes into play for Apple to explain what types of files and folders are hidden from view by the Finder program. So the actual definition of what it is, is simply how Finder works.

The best way to find the full list of files and folders hidden by Finder is to reverse engineer the Finder.app program.